# Publish asp.net web app to IIS over existing asp.net web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I have an app made with ASP.NET Core and I published/deployed it to IIS. It has a database with multiple tables, and multiple rows of data. I was tasked with recreating the web app again and improving it. I used ASP.NET Core again, this time the database and tables are all different. I am using the same url as the old one, just a different app with different database.

My question is, can I just add the connection string in the `appsettings.json` file to the new app with just a different database name and transfer the `publish profile` over to the new app? Can I do this and it will add the new web app to the url and simply override the other web app currently running on it? If so do I need to create the database on the server before hand, then reference it in the connection string? Or when I publish the new web app, the new database will be created?

I can add more details if necessary. I just want to know if connecting the new app will be as easy as adding the same connection string. Here is `appsettings.json` currently running

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=Server-Name;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "https_port"; 443,
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

To be more specific. I just want to add replace the current web app with the new one. The database, code is different in the new app. I just want to use the same url which is hosted on IIS server, but with different code. Basically I don't want to buy a new domain name from somewhere. I want to push new project onto server and host it.

Can I just change `Database=DatabaseName` to `Database=NewDatabaseName` inside the connection string?

Comment: Is the difference between databases 1 and 2 just the name of the database? If yes, then it will work.

Comment: No the databases are different, I added and removed tables from the current database, also column have different data types.

Comment: @SudipShrestha but even then, can I create the new database on the server then connect to the server just with a different database specified? I am not worried about the data transferring over, I just want to connect the new app to the url on the server and then recreate the data for the new site

Comment: Then it will not work. You will need to change the models etc.

Comment: @SudipShrestha sorry I was not specific. It is a different web app, different models, different database, slightly differing views etc. I just want to use the same url, simply a matter of publishing site to the same server, same url, just different app. This way I won't need to buy another domain name

Comment: you could host this app as an application under the same site that way you don't need to change the URL and no need to buy the different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it and all I had to do was create the new database on the IIS server in SSMS, create a folder to publish the code to on the server, and also direct the url to point to the folder in IIS.

On my app, in `appsettings.json`, just copy the same `connectionstring` over from the old project to the new project, just update the database name.

This did what I expected, just replaced the url/website, with the code from my new app.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems like you are trying to host two applications in IIS under the same domain.

When doing it manually, you simply "Add Application" in your site.
[image: IIS Manually]

If you are publishing it from Visual Studio, you can do a Web Deploy or publish to a folder.
**Web Deploy:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-iis?view=vs-2019

**Publish Folder:**

1. Create an application manually in IIS.
2. Share the app folder with you.
3. Publish from Visual Studio to the folder.
   [image: Publish to folder]

***Having said that...* I don't recommend publish to your production directly from your machine. I recommend using a CD pipeline from your repo. If you don't have one yet, I recommend using Azure DevOps.**